# If a condition is not fulfilled return data for that user, else another query

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have a table with these data:

```
  ID, Name, LastName, Date, Type
```

I have to query the table for the user with ID 1.
Get the row, if the Type of that user is not 2, then return that user, else return all users that have the same LastName and Date.

What would be the most efficient way to do this ?
What I had done is :

```
query1 = SELECT * FROM clients where ID = 1

query2 = SELECT * FROM client WHERE LastName = %s AND Date= %s
```

And I execute the first query

```
 cursor.execute(sql)
 rows = cursor.fetchall()
 for row in rows:
     if(row['Type'] ==2 )
          cursor.execute(sql2(row['LastName'], row['Date']))
     Save results
      else
          results = rows?
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this using Joins?
Example if I only have a left join, how would I also ask if the type of the user is 2 ?
And if there is multiple rows to be returned, how to assign them to an array of objects in python?

Comment: is there any reason you removed the other question? the same question was asked under a different name and I provided an answer showing how to do this with joins.

Comment: @eagle I had a delete account scheduled apparently, I apologize.
I replied to your comment because I hadn't properly explained what I needed.
But thank you! It was very helpful, as I realized my queries were wrong initially lol.

Comment: so what is it you want here? seems like the same exact thing with joins, also you execute `sql` and `sql2` but you label the queries as `query1` and `query2`

Comment: I initially would execute query1 because I needed to check whether Type is equal to 2.
If it is, then look for the users with those lastnames and of same gender, if it's not then return that user.
Since you said to use joins, I wasn't sure how to achieve this with one query and assign it on python.
Here I just was giving a better overview of my problem.

Comment: so you need all the results regardless? I am confused because your else statement simply returns the results asis

Comment: I have one user with ID 1 .
If the Type  column of that User is 2, then look for all the other users with the same last name and date and return them.
Else, only return the User with ID 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just do two queries to avoid loops here:

```
q1 = """
     SELECT c.* FROM clients c where c.ID = 1
     """

q2 = """
     SELECT b.* FROM clients b
     JOIN (SELECT c.* FROM
           clients c
           c.ID = 1 
           AND
           c.Type = 2) a
     ON
     a.LastName = b.LastName
     AND
     a.Date = b.Date
     """
```

Then you can just execute both queries and you'll have all the desired results you want without the need for loops since your loop will execute `n` number of queries where `n` is equal to the number of rows that match as opposed to grabbing it all in one join in one pass. Without more specifics as the desired data structure of final results, as it seems you only care about saving the results, this should give you what you want.

Comment: But if the Type is not equal to 2, then the second query does not need to be executed at all.
Will this way be executed and return no results?

Comment: if theres no one with type 2 then it will return no rows, but this is more efficient than looping through every row for sure, a database will do this much faster than a python loop

Comment: There is only ONE User with the ID of 1.
So I have to check His type, if it's 2 then execute the query that will join, if it's not then return The data for that user only.
I don't have to loop to find if the Type is 2. Because it's only One row.

Comment: ok so what is the problem with your original approach then? I don't understand what it is you want

Comment: ..my initial issue was only assigning and passing variables. But then you brought up joins, so they're obviously more efficient approach.
In my question here I am asking whether what i was doing can be achieved using for example a Left Join, that will return only the user itself his type is not 2, and all other users if it's 2.
So I liked your initial approach, but it didn't take into consideration the Type and that it's one row.
If I do an if else in python, then do I need a join, or is it better to have a SQL Statement and put the condition in WHERE lastname = the first userlast name etc.